# Power BI (paginated report): Override default error messages

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

Would you prompt me please, where to find end edit the configuration code  of Power BI report (below).

The purpose: to override default error messages.

Server: PowerBI

Report type: paginated report (SSRS analogue)

Code source: [article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/override-error-messages)

Configuration code:

```
let config = {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: embedReportId,
    permissions: permissions,
    settings: {
        hideErrors: true
    }
};
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/override-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration to edit. The article from your question suggest to [handle the errors yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/override-error-messages#how-to-override-errors). `hideErrors: true` means that Power BI will not show the error. Then you must handle `error` event and show a message to the user, that something happened. What will show is up to you. Information about the actual error will be provided in the `event` parameter. In case of error, it will implement [`IError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#error-events-relevant-for-all-embeds) interface and you can look at the values of `message`, `detailedMessage` and `errorCode` properties to decide what to show to the user.

```
report.off("error");
report.on("error", function(event) {
    // Handle errors <-- This is the place, where you must write code to show a message
});
```

For more in-depth information how to handle events when embedding Power BI, see [How to handle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events) article.

Comment: Andrey, thank you very much for your answer. Would you prompt me, where can I write / edit the code described in your answer? I'm not familliar with JS, therefore I can't understand: whether I should edit a web page or something in Power BI server? If this can only be done by using BI Client APIs., what are the first steps to use APIs? Does it require JS knowledge?

Comment: Yes, it requires JavaScript programming skills. The code for handling the events is in the same file, where the configuration code (`let config = {... `) is.

Comment: Andrey, thank you. Is it possible to find the file with configuration code in the power BI Server, and what can be the name of the file?

Comment: This is not part of Power BI. This is a source code of the application, where the report is embedded.